# Is Expo's react-native SQLite transaction a real SQL transaction?

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

In Expo, the react-native + extra development environment,
the SQLite API in react-native uses the notion of 'transaction'. However there is no discussion of committing that transaction. 
Is the RN notion of transaction just a set of consecutive calls SQLite? or is it a real transaction in the SQLite sense (i.e. all commands succeed or they are rolled back). If the latter, how does one correctly test that the transaction does or doesn't need to be retried? 
If not, then I presume one has to do transaction and commit commands on one's own. Still how does one correctly handle a failed transaction?

Comment: You're going to need to add more detail like what SQLite API are you using. The only one I'm familiar with is [`react-native-sqlite-storage`](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) and **the docs there clearly explain that they are real SQL transactions**. The call even has onSuccess and onError callbacks for handling everything.

Comment: Done. It is the Expo provided SQLite API.

Comment: Expo's SQLite implementation is based on [`react-native-sqlite-2`](https://github.com/craftzdog/react-native-sqlite-2) which itself is based on [`cordova-plugin-sqlite-2`](https://github.com/nolanlawson/cordova-plugin-sqlite-2), so the docs there would be a good place to start. I'm not familiar enough with either so I can't give a definitive answer.

Comment: @Michel have you found the answer to this yet?